# Make item to bottom of dynamic object array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a dynamic object array like below. I always need to show the "Other" at the bottom of the list. This is a dynamic array and new items can be added to the list and can't sort by id as id is autoincremented number. How can do sort this in Javascript?
Dynamic Array :

```
 [{name: Apple, id: 1},
  {name: Other, id: 2 },
  {name: watermelon, id:3}
  {name: Orange, id: 4}]
```

Expected result :

```
 [{name: Apple, id: 1},
  {name: watermelon, id:3}
  {name: Orange, id: 4},
  {name: Other, id: 2 }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by:

1. Find the index of the item you wish to move to the end
2. Removing it from the list
3. Adding it to the end of the list

```js
const data = [
  {name: 'Apple', id: 1},
  {name: 'Other', id: 2 },
  {name: 'watermelon', id:3},
  {name: 'Orange', id: 4},
];

// find item
const otherIndex = data.findIndex(item => item.name === 'Other');

if (otherIndex !== -1) {
  const otherItem = data[otherIndex];
  
  // make a copy of data
  const reorderedData = Array.from(data);
  
  // remove item
  reorderedData.splice(otherIndex, 1);
  
  // add item into the new list
  reorderedData.push(otherItem);
  
  console.log(reorderedData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array#splice` (or immutable variations) to always add new results before the end of the array.

```
array.splice(-1,0,newItem);
```

For an immutable example:

```
array = [...array.slice(0,-1),newItem,array[array.length-1]]
```